ORIGINAL_LOGIN() returns incorrect user name (AD vs local account)
I'm trying to switch between user contexts but ORIGINAL_LOGIN() returns some magic AD account rather than the local machine account I connected with. This makes it impossible to switch back to the original caller context. I'm connecting as a local Windows user.
SELECT ORIGINAL_LOGIN(), SYSTEM_USER

returns:
MicrosoftAccount\name@email.com | localMachine\localUser

The login I connected with is indeed localMachine\localUser. I'm not even sure where the MicrosoftAccount\name@email.com account comes from, Windows sort of invented this on its own.
Now consider this stored procedure:
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE spTest WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER AS
BEGIN
    -- Do high-privilege things ...

    EXECUTE AS LOGIN = ORIGINAL_LOGIN(); -- Fails!
    -- Impersonate caller, check some permissions
    REVERT;

    -- Do more high-privilege things ...
END
GO

EXEC spTest;

The EXECUTE AS LOGIN impersonation invariably fails with:
Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'MicrosoftAccount\name@email.com', error code 0x54b.

Obviously, since MicrosoftAccount\name@email.com is not used or configured anywhere. This makes ORIGINAL_LOGIN() completely useless to us, and I have no idea how to temporarily switch back to the caller context.
Note that the code above is for demonstration only. The actual code base is significantly more complex with chains of stored procedure calls and triggers involved.
How can I get ORIGINAL_LOGIN() to return the actual original login?

We are not exactly using Azure/Entra AD, or at least not on purpose. But new Windows really tries hard to tie you to the Azure/Entra AD framework whether you like it or not.
exec xp_logininfo only exposes localMachine\localUser. There is nothing to tie it to the Azure/Entra AD account. The solution works fine when there is no Azure/Entra AD involved.
If possible, I'd like to completely disable the Azure/Entra AD feature for SQL Server. I don't even know why SQL Server chooses it over localMachine\localUser.

I would need to know more abut the setup to understand where this is coming from. On a normal installation of SQL Server 2022 on Windows Server 2022 this should not look like that.
I usually see this on Windows client machines with a Microsoft Live Login active.

@AndreasWolter I think you're onto something. This system is installed locally at thousands of customers, most of them are running Windows Server as per recommendation but with such a large customer base you'll always have the odd ones out. I'll have a look at getting rid of the Microsoft Live Login, but it's problematic... It would be great if I could just tell SQL Server to ignore the Live Login.

If there are Windows Client machines involved which are nowadays almost forced to use Microsoft Live accounts, then you will always encounter this issue.
This behavior is not documented to my knowledge and would require a bug report/support case to have some engineer to try understand what's really going on let alone fix it.
From SQL Server's perspective the Microsoft Live account is the original identity that opened the connection. You can see that in select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions. Hence all calls to ORIGINAL_LOGIN go to the Microsoft Live identity.
You will need to find a different logic or flow so accomplish what you intend I fear.

It feels so close; sys.dm_exec_sessions gives me the current elevated OWNER login (e.g. 'sa') and the original Live login (MicrosoftAccount\name@email.com). And xp_logininfo gives me the correct localMachine\localUser, but I don't know how to match it to the current session. Where does xp_logininfo pull its data from?

xp_logininfo uses Win API calls to NetLocalGroupGetMembers and NetUserGetGroups - documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netlocalgroupgetmembers and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netusergetgroups
But I am not sure how this can help you. I would have to dig more and probably require help from some Engineer. Sorry

That's an awesomely informed answer, thank you! I was hoping it was perhaps pulled from some public sys.dm_* view but this is a great explanation.

I see what you mean. So no: xp's generally were originally created specifically for running code that cannot be solved within SQL alone.
